# How to get size of zip files in a folder and save the name of file and size of zip file in excel

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file which gets the size of zip files available in a folder and save the folder name with its appropriate file size in a .CSV file. I used the below command but I only got 1 output because when the loop ends the last result is fetched in the .CSV file

```
for %%I in (*.txt) do @echo %%~nI,%%I >C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\out.csv
```

I want the result in a format as size in a cell and whole path in different cell

Hope to get a answer soon

Answer (score 2):

```
(for %%I in (*.zip) do echo(%%~nI,%%~zI)>C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\out.csv
```

To get only the folder's name with the calculated size of all ZIP files together use this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%a IN ('dir *.zip') DO (
    CALL SET "size=%%free%%"
    SET "free=%%a"
)
(ECHO(%cd%,%size%)>C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\out.csv
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: To get, what the OP _really_ wants (`save the folder name with its appropriate file size`) ie. size of the ZIP files together in the folder the code must be changed. see my edit, please.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for bothering, this answer showed up in the low quality queue due to its length - then again personally I appreciate a concise answer, if it's clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for a list of `.zip` files, you might not want to loop over `.txt` files. To append to a file, you need to use `>>` instead of `>`.

```
FOR %%I IN (*.zip) DO @ECHO %%~nI,%%~zI >> C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\out.csv
```

**Update:** So the question was how to *recursively* look in a directory tree for `.zip` files and output their path and size separated by a comma. It can be done like this:

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('dir /s /b *.zip') DO @ECHO %%I,%%~zI >> C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\out.csv
```

If I run this in my JDK 1.6 folder, the output looks like this:

```
C:\dev\jdk16024\src.zip,19717891
C:\dev\jdk16024\jre\lib\deploy\ffjcext.zip,16801
```

Comment: %%I was unexpected at this time.
The above is the error that I am getting when running the command

Comment: I want to search in each and every folder and then get the whole path that from which all destinations it got the zip file. So hope you can help me in that too.\

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand what you want to do. Can you provide an example how the output should look like? Please add it to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: Suppose I want to search (.zip) file in a drive ie D:\ then I want such a script which can search the whole D:\ drive i.e each and every folder in it and then display the path where the .zip file is located in the drive. I want this location as well as its size in a .CSV file.